# Trying to filter out invalid URL characters in C regex

Tags: c, regex, string, escaping, match

I created code here that is supposed to determine if a URL contains an invalid set of characters, and regex may be a good way to go.

The problem here is that the target string in this code (stored in the value of the char array variable "find") is not being taken as a valid match even though my regex means match any character between square brackets at least once, and an exclamation mark is listed in the character set.

Also, when compiling with all warnings on, I receive these warnings:

```
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\#'
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\!'
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\$'
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\&'
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\-'
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\;'
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\='
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\]'
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\_'
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\~'
```

And the one that bugs me is:

```
./test2.c:6:25: warning: unknown escape sequence '\]'
```

because if I don't escape it, then I'm using it to end a set of characters to check for, yet I want that character to be included as a literal character in the check.

What can I do to fix this regex issue?

I want to be able to make an apache module from this after in C so that if a hacker tries using strange unacceptable characters in the URL, he will be directed to an error page. Once I figure this regex mess out, then I'll be on my way.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(){
  const char* regex="/^[\#\!\$\&\-\;\=\?\[\]\_\~]+$/";
  const char* find="!!!";
  regex_t r;int s;
  if ((s=regcomp(&r,regex,REG_EXTENDED)) != 0){
    printf("Error compiling\n");return 1;
  }
  const int maxmat=10;
  regmatch_t ml[maxmat];
  if (regexec(&r,find,maxmat,ml,0) != 0){
    printf("No match\n");
  }else{
    printf("Matched");
  }
  regfree(&r);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid"? A good number of the characters in your regex are perfectly valid in a URL, and some of them have special significance.  You inhibit useful functionality if you disallow `&`, `=`, and `#` in particular; and `_`, `~`, and `-` have regular, undramatic usages.

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to work for me:

```
char* regex="(.*)[#!$&-;=?_~]+";
```

Comment: You skipped a good number of the characters in the class, and `&-;` is an ill-defined character range.

Answer (score 0):

The various warnings you got were from the C compiler itself, not the regex compiler. The C compiler does not know anything about regular expressions or character sets. It does know about string lierals and the escape character for C strings is also '\', so it is trying to interpret all of the backslash characters as C string escape character for things like:

```
\n - newline 
\" - quote character
\\ - backslash character
```

In order to pass a backslash to the regex engine, you must first escape it in the C string literal. Simply replace all of your `\` with `\\` and you will have more luck with you regular expressions.

If you have the option of compiling with C++11 compliant compiler you have the option of using raw strings, which get rid of all of the escaping in normal C strings:

```
strlen("\n")      => 1
strlen(R"(\n)");  => 2
```

In the second case the string starts with `R"(` and continues until it finds `)"`. So the second string consists of two characters `\` and `n` rather than a single newline character.

This is very handy for using with regular expressions as it does not require multiple levels of escape characters.

Comment: Backslashing stuff which doesn't need to be backslashed is still bad form.

Answer (score 0):

A common beginner mistake is the assumption that you need or want to backslash stuff in a regular expression class.  You don't; inside square brackets, every character represents just itself.  There are a few special cases which require special handling, but not with backslashing.

- If you want a literal `^` in the character class, it mustn't go first.
- If you want a literal `]` in the character class, it needs to go first (after any `^` to specify negation).
- If you want a literal `-` in the character class, it needs to go first (even before any `]`, but after a `^` for negating the character class) or last.

By convention, if you want both `]` and `[`, you usually put them next to each other.

So, you want

```
const char* regex="^[-][#!$&;=?_~]+$";
```

The slashes you had before and after the regex looked like you thought they were necessary or useful as regex separators; but they're not, so I took them out.

This will match a string consisting solely of the characters in your class.  By your description, that's not really what you want.  But you don't need a regex for finding an occurrence of one of these characters somewhere in a string; look at the general C string search functions.